# Mapping ros::Publishers to different dynamically generated topic names

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I am programming a tcp server to connect with another  machine not using ROS. The main idea is to generate a topic for each connection, using the port value as identifier of the connection. So I use an std::map to pair ros::publisher and topic name:

```
std::map<std::string, ros::Publisher> comms_map;
```

When a new connection is received:

```
void addNewConnection(int socket, struct sockaddr_in addr)
{
    CONNECTION aux;
    aux.socket= socket;
    aux.port= addr.sin_port;
    aux.addr= addr.sin_addr.s_addr;
    connections.push_back(aux);
    
    //create the new publisher
    std::string topic_name = getTopicName(aux.port); //Creates the topic name "/tcp_server_data_pNUMPORT"
    ros::Publisher pub_aux = nh->advertise<std_msgs::String>(topic_name.c_str(), 1);
    comms_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, ros::Publisher>(topic_name,pub_aux));
    
    ROS_INFO("Added connection -> socket: %d port: %u addr: %ld",aux.socket, aux.port, aux.addr);
}
```

So, when I receive data, I try to publish over the correct ros::Publisher, using this code:

```
void publishMsgToTopic(int socket, char *buffer)
{
    //publish buffer to topic tcp_server_data_pXXXXXX
    std_msgs::String msg;
    unsigned long addr;
    unsigned short port;
    
    findConnection(socket,addr,port);
    std::string topic_name = getTopicName(port); 
    
    ROS_INFO("publishMsgToTopic -> socket %d port: %u addr: %ld. Topic: %s Message: %s",
                    socket, port, addr, (char *)(topic_name.c_str()), buffer);
    
    msg.data = std::string(buffer);
    
    ros::Publisher aux = comms_map.find(topic_name)->second;
    //also tested:
    // ros::Publisher aux = comms_map[topic_name];
    // ros::Publisher aux = comms_map.at(topic_name);
    
    aux.publish(msg);
}
```

Although the topic is created, and I do not receive any error, the topic does not publish any data !
Everything else in the process has been tested and works.
IMPORTANT: each connection is attended in a child (fork process)

Could anyone give a hand about this?

Thank you very much in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226335/mapping-ros::publishers-to-different-dynamically-generated-topic-names/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[problem with publish in fork() process](http://answers.ros.org/question/220760/problem-with-publish-in-fork-process/) is probably relevant here.

---

Edit: you probably have looked into it, but would something like [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) work? Quote from the package description: "Rosbridge provides a JSON API to ROS functionality for non-ROS programs".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2016-02-12**:
Thank you a lot, I will have a look t othe fork() problem. I have already looked at rosbrigde, but the client is a very limited machine, not capable of constructing JSON files...